# Splitting string with dates by '/'-character and getting ancient/latest date as new column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, date, string, format

I have dates separated by `'/'` character in column `"date"` in format *RRMMDD* as on the screenshot below:

[image: input_qgis]

I want to separate dates into another columns `"date_from"`, `"date_to"` and convert dates into *YY.MM.DD* format by adding dots as on following picture

[image: output_qgis]

In QGIS, there is any formula to separate values between `'/'` character and export MIN/MAX values into another columns?

Comment: When there are three dates you want the earliest and the most recent of the three?

Comment: do we agree it's text in your first row ? then you should look in the field calculator and use some regex and conversion function to cast it to date format in a new column. Working with date object will be more practical and then you can show it in whatever format you need, don't use text.

Comment: Yes, it is text in first row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PyQGIS:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0]
fieldnames = ['date', 'date_from', 'date_to']

indices = [lyr.fields().indexFromName(fn) for fn in fieldnames[1:]] #Find indices for the fields to update
attrmap = {} #A dictionary to hold the new values
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    dates = f[fieldnames[0]].split('/') #Split date string into a list of strings
    dates = [dt.strptime(x, '%y%m%d') for x in dates] #Convert strings to dates
    fromdate, todate = [dt.strftime(x, '%y.%m.%d') for x in [min(dates), max(dates)]] #Extract min and max date and convert back to strings with dots between year month and day
    attrmap[f.id()] = {indices[0]:fromdate, indices[1]:todate} #Store in the dictionary
    
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrmap) #Update values
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create new columns from your original columns in the Field calculator of QGIS.

From what I see in your original format you can try things in my screenshot.
we parse the text of the original field and put in a new date field.

it's better to store these thing in a date format field and use a format "YY.MM.DD" to show it

if you absolutely want a text, recast it in a text format and declare text format

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Despite a nice answer from @Maximilien jaffrès, I will suggest another formula:

### For min `"date_from"` i.e. the ancient date:

```
format_date(
    to_date(
        datetime_from_epoch(
        array_min(
            array_foreach(
                string_to_array("dates", '/'), -- here define the field with dates
                epoch(
                    make_date(
                        to_int(substr(@element,5,4)), --year
                        to_int(substr(@element,3,2)), --month
                        to_int(substr(@element,0,2)) --day
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        ),
        'dd.MM.yy' --format of the date output
    )
```

### For max `"date_to"` i.e. the latest date:

```
format_date(
    to_date(
        datetime_from_epoch(
        array_max(
            array_foreach(
                string_to_array("dates", '/'), -- here define the field with dates
                epoch(
                    make_date(
                        to_int(substr(@element,5,4)), --year
                        to_int(substr(@element,3,2)), --month
                        to_int(substr(@element,0,2)) --day
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        ),
        'dd.MM.yy' --format of the date output
    )
```

Both above formulas using the following functions: [`string_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#string-to-array), [`array_foreach()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-foreach), [`epoch()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#epoch), [`make_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-date), [`to_int()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-int), [`substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#substr), [`datetime_from_epoch()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#datetime-from-epoch), [`to_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#expression-function-date-and-time-to-date), [`format_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#expression-function-string-format-date).